# Домочадцы: происхождение слова

Tags: этимология

Домочадцы — жители одного дома. Но интересует второй корень слова "-чад-". Это от слова "чадить" или от слова "чадо"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

От "чадо". Домочадцами раньше называли "дитят дома", домашнюю прислугу, а также приживалов, приживалок и пр. не членов семьи.