# Этимология слова «домочадцы»

Tags: этимология, историческая-грамматика, историческая-фонетика

Почему слово *домочадец* — славянизм, а не исконно русское производное от *дом* и *чадо*?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/25122/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, потому что чадо - устаревшее  заимствование из церковно-славянского, согласно Фасмеру:

https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D1%87/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE

ча́до домоча́дцы мн. Заимств. из цслав., укр. ча́до «дитя», (на)ща́док «потомок», блр. чадо́ «злое дитя, упрямец» (Брандт, РФВ 21, 215), др.-русск. чадо, чадь ж. «дети, люди, народ», ст.-слав. чѩдо τέκνον (Остром., Клоц., Супр.), болг. че́до «дитя», сербохорв. чȅдо, чеш. стар. čаd, čád «мальчик, юноша», др.-польск, czędo «дитя», dо szczędu «до последнего потомка» Праслав. čędо все считали раньше заимств. из герм. (др.-сакс., д.-в.-н. kind); см. И. Шмидт, Pluralb. 13; Мi. ЕW 32; Мейе, ét. 110, 266; Ягич, AfslPh 23, 537; Уленбек, AfslPh 15, 485. Эту точку зрения оспаривали на том основании, что это единственный пример, где č- соответствует герм. k- перед передними гласными (обычно с-, ср. ст.-слав. цѩта).

Собственно, дитя - тоже древнее славянское слово, а собственно русское - детина, встречается в памятниках 13 века (дитя, юноша). Сейчас используется как разговорное в значении "рослый и сильный молодой мужчина".

Учебный словарь"Староболгаризмы и церковнославянизмы в лексике русского литературного языка"под редакцией проф. К.Г. Бабова (Софийский университет „Климент Охридски"
София, 1986) подаёт это слово как церковнославянизм: 
http://macedonia.kroraina.com/pfr1/pfr1_1-3.htm#3b

домочадец - слуга, родившийся и воспитанный в доме; человек, живущий в доме на правах члена семьи; вначале было ещё значение "уроженец и коренной житель данной местности".

Было ещё слово чадь, оно соотносится со словом челядь - дворовые слуги помещика, люди.

Г.П.Цыганенко говорит, что "чадо" в его современной форме появилось в памятниках письменности в 11 веке, развилось из праславянского. Памятники письменности были на церковно-славянском языке, оттуда оно и пришло в русский - уже с носовым юсом малым (с ним вместе пришло исчадие - -потомство, детище в значении "порождение чего-либо ужасного"), чадити (через юс малый) - родить.

Comment: Ну а почему заимствование-то? На каких основаниях?

Comment: На основании того, что старославянский язык – это первый литературный, письменный язык славян, в основу которого легли болгаро-македонские говоры, относившиеся к южной группе славянских языков.Значит, не является языком-предком русского языка, это язык южнославянской группы.

Comment: Увы, Людмила, это никак не связано с обоснованием принадлежности слова _домочадец_ к заимствованиям из церковнославянского. Мне интересны лингвистические признаки, благодаря которым мы делаем тот или иной вывод.

Comment: Лингвистический признак - написание  через юс малый, сейчас добавлю в ответ.

Comment: Но ведь в древнерусских памятниках также встречаются юсы — так что нет, не то :(

Comment: В древнерусском языке носовые гласные в 10 в. изменились в 'чистые' гласные. Поэтому в древнерусской графике 11 в.юс большой стал обозначать звук [у], а юс малый  - [а] после смягчённого согласного: 'рука', - 'пять'. С середины 12 в. юс большой исчезает из русского письма (временно был возрожден в 15 в.). К юсу малому восходит по начертанию буква 'я' современного русского алфавита.

Comment: Людмила, ну и о чем же это говорит?.. «и велми, ре́че, чѧ́до. и рече єму александръ» — это из древнерусского памятника («Александрия»).

Comment: И что? В древнерусских памятниках очень много старославянизмов.

Comment: "Александрия" - переводной роман об Александре Македонском, перевели его на древнерусский сербы, там вообще почти один церковно-славянский, он так и называется "сербский извод"

Comment: Людмила, да хорошо, хорошо, но чадо и без юса писали — почему вы считаете их написание признаком заимствований из старославянского? Древнерусские авторы писали то ук, то юс — что с того? Почему автор не мог по ошибке, «на автомате» написать юс не там, где надо? Если мы говорим о том, что рефлексы сочетаний с плавными разные в южнославянских и восточнославянских, то это надежный признак. А юсы-то...

Comment: Aer, я не считаю это признаком заимствования, я не ставлю это под сомнение, потому что лексическое значение русского чадо, развившегося из праславянского, - дитя, а в слове домочадцы значение религиозное , из Писания - чадца - люди с духовным родством. Домочадцы - все, кто живёт в доме и сроднились. Это заимствование из церковно-славянского, освоенное  русским.